# Cant redirect to another page in htaccess using php

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have problem to redirect page using in htaccess
a href> tag

**http://localhost:82/firstsource(htaccess)/single/326/abc**

this is my url of my single product page but when i redirect to my index page then url becomes

**http://localhost:82/firstsource(htaccess)/single/326/index**

and page not redirect to index page

**Options +FollowSymlinks**

**RewriteEngine on**

**RewriteRule ^single/([0-9]+)/([a-z-0-9]+)$ single.php?pid=$1&pname=$2 [NC]**

this is my htaccess code.
Please help me to solve this problem.